# Renyi entropy (zeroth order)

Tags: information-theory, entropy

I am reading a book on information theory, therein has been introduced Renyi entropy of order $\alpha$ as

$S_{\alpha} = \frac{1}{1-\alpha}\log(Tr\rho^{\alpha})$,

where $\rho$ is density matrix.

It has been claimed that for $\alpha = 0$ there is a subadditivity relation as

$S_{0} (\rho_{AB})\leq S_{0} (\rho_{A})+S_{0} (\rho_{B})$.

I cannot see how one can prove this. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the definition the formula you want to prove is turning into:

$\log(Tr\rho_{AB})\leq\log(Tr\rho_A)+\log(Tr\rho_B)$

Now using the property of sums of logarithms this is equivalent to:

$\log(Tr\rho_{AB})\leq\log(Tr\rho_A\cdot Tr\rho_B)$

which finally comes down to $Tr\rho_{AB}\leq Tr\rho_A\cdot Tr\rho_B$.

This last inequality holds as all $\rho$ are density matrices.

Comment: I have never seen the last inequality. How can one prove it?